# Using acceptsMouseMovedEvents for SpriteKit mouse actions with Storyboards and Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, sprite-kit, iboutlet, xcode-storyboard

I have created a SpriteKit scene by referencing a custom `NSView` using Storyboards in Xcode. However, I cannot implement any `mouseMoved` events using SpriteKit because I do not know how to reference the program's `NSWindow`to set its `acceptsMouseMovedEvents` property to "true".

How can I create an `@IBOutlet` reference to my `NSWindow` in my `AppDelegate.swift` file so that I can change this property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure an `NSTrackingArea` object to track the movement of the mouse as well as when the cursor enters or exits a view. To create an `NSTrackingArea` object, you specify a region of a view where you want mouse events to be tracked, the owner that will receive the mouse event messages, and when the tracking will occur (e.g., in the key window). The following is an example of how to add a tracking area to a view. Add to your `SKScene` subclass, such as GameScene.swift.

**Swift 3 and 4**

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    // Create a tracking area object with self as the owner (i.e., the recipient of mouse-tracking messages
    let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: view.frame, options: [.activeInKeyWindow, .mouseMoved], owner: self, userInfo: nil)
    // Add the tracking area to the view
    view.addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
}

// This method will be called when the mouse moves in the view
override func mouseMoved(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let location = theEvent.location(in: self)
    print(location)
}
```

**Swift 2**

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    // Create a tracking area object with self as the owner (i.e., the recipient of mouse-tracking messages
    let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: view.frame, options: NSTrackingAreaOptions.ActiveInKeyWindow | NSTrackingAreaOptions.MouseMoved, owner: self, userInfo: nil)
    // Add the tracking area to the view
    view.addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
}

// This method will be called when the mouse moves in the view
override func mouseMoved(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let location = theEvent.locationInNode(self)
    println(location)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An update for 0x141E's answer:

```
override func didChangeSize(_ oldSize: CGSize) {
    guard let newRect = view?.bounds else {return}

    let options = NSTrackingArea.Options(rawValue: NSTrackingArea.Options.activeInKeyWindow.rawValue | NSTrackingArea.Options.mouseMoved.rawValue)
    let userInfo = ["SKMouseInput": 1]
    let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: newRect, options: options, owner: self, userInfo: userInfo)
    if let previousTrackingAreas = view?.trackingAreas {
        for area in previousTrackingAreas {
            if let theInfo = area.userInfo {
                if let _ = theInfo["SKMouseInput"]  {
                    view?.removeTrackingArea(area)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    view?.addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
}
```

This SKScene method override will be called shortly after initialization, will allow immunity to window size changes and will clean up the old tracking area. Note that it will still require the mouseMoved override as well.

Comment: 'allow immunity to window size changes' sounds good, but if I manually resize my window, this method does not get called; you need to manually set the size of the scene or scaleMode = .resizeFill to trigger it. 
Good catch overall, though.